# Convert Geo location latitude and longitude to numeric format?

Tags: c#, geolocation, number-formatting

I have Geo location coordinates as `latitude - 47.60529` and `longitude - -122.33905`. I need to format this into a numeric format as  `47__2E__60529` and `__2D__122__2E__33905` ?

Can anyone direct me on how to do this formatting?

Comment: I didn't notice from the title it says convert to custom numeric format... I guess you are the only one that knows what this custom thing is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess something like this will get you close:

```
using System.Globalization;

public static string customConvert(double num)
{
    NumberFormatInfo customFormat = new NumberFormatInfo();
    customFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = "__2E__";
    customFormat.NegativeSign = "__2D__";
    return num.ToString(customFormat);
}
```

To use, something like this:

```
string latitude = customConvert(47.60529);
```

I'm not sure about the `-e__2F_` string at the end of your example though...